# How are device driver development and linux kernel programming related/different?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

This might be a stupid question but I am confused and google couldn't help.

I know Linux is the Kernel which is the heart of many distros( Ubuntu, Mint). But when we say "Linux kernel programming", what do we exactly mean? Is it Bash scripting?

And how it is related to the device driver development? (Do we mean that the hardware is running linux kernel and we do kernel programming to support peripherals, this is ,in general, device driver development in relation to linux? )

Answer (score 2):

**Device driver development is a subset of Linux kernel programming.**

Device driver development is writing or modifying kernel modules that will handle a device. A device driver is a special case of kernel modules. 

Kernel modules are codes that work from within the kernel and do privileged tasks.

Kernel modules are an integral part of Linux kernel programming. That is how device driver development and Linux kernel programming are related. The former is a part of the latter.

Also, device drivers will ultimately be inserted into the kernel, and will work in a kernel context. That is, device drivers ultimately become a part of the kernel.

Hence driver development is a subset within Linux kernel programming.

Answer (score 1):

Linux Kernel Programming is something which involves kernel components, meaning - kernel data structures and headers. A program in which one uses the existing kernel features or enhances the current features is a kernel program, typically a kernel module. In a way even the Bash scripting can be called as Linux Kernel programming. The device driver in a broad term is nothing but a set of interrupt handlers. Having said that, a device driver is a kernel program in itself as it uses the Linux kernel capabilities which is ported on a device/hardware. So in short the relation between the two is Device driver development is a form of Linux Kernel Programming.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two kinds of programs running on your computer : the kernel, which has access to the computer hardware, and "userland" programs which ask the kernel to do low-level stuff (allocate memory, send data to the network, ...).

To do this, the kernel must know how to interact with some given piece of hardware. This is what we call "device drivers". In Linux, the device drivers are implemented as kernel module and device driver programming is akin to kernel programming because you deal with low-level operations straight to the metal instead of higher-level operations that go through the kernel.

Bash scripting is programming a shell (Bash) to run userland programs that themselves use the kernel to do the actual work. Bash-scripting is userland programming.